# Cron job meteor send email

Tags: meteor, cron-task

I want to schedule email function to run at once in a day, But it showing me an error -"( Mail not sent; to enable sending, set the MAIL_URL environment variable. )", This message is showing only in cron job email function. New registered users are getting emails successfully. Can anyone please help me here why is this happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your cron job code and have you set "export MAIL_URL=smtp://emialid@gmail.com:passwordhere@smtp.gmail.com:465" ?

Comment: function sendMail(email) {
   Email.send(email);
}
function addCronMail(id, details) {
    SyncedCron.add({
        name: "Scheduled Vaccination Email",
        schedule: function(parser) {
           return parser.recur().every(3).minute();
        },
        job: function() {
            sendMail(email);
        }
    });
}
Meteor.startup(function() {
     var email = {
           from: "test@local.com",
              to: "john@test.test",
              subject: "Sub",
              text: "text"

           };       
    sendMail(email);
    SyncedCron.start();
});

Comment: This is my code, which is on server file.I am doing my development on local machine. I did not export. Or i have no idea how to export.

Comment: before running meteor run command in your console paste this command with your login-password. then do meteor run "export MAIL_URL=smtp://emialid@gmail.com:passwordhere@smtp.gmail.co‌​m:465"  and in your server code inside meteor.startup do console.log(process.env); and check your MAIL_URL

Comment: Why is this happening - Email.send working on other pages like on user registration, but not in cron job. in cron job it saying for setting env :(

Comment: Remember, I am on my local machine. I just got this issue from yesterday every time i failed.

Comment: priyanka its not related to cron job. Cron is just to repeat a task thats it. its like a function which repeat after a fixed time. if we want to send Email using meteor we need email id. are you using angular 2 - meteor or just meteor ?

Comment: I am using meteor, I want an answer why only here it is asking for setting env and not for on other places where same send email is working.

Comment: ok can you tell me from which email id you are getting or sending email ?

Comment: And i used process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://"+decodeURIComponent("un@gmail.com")+":"+encodeURIComponent('password')+"@smtp.gmail.com:465/";

console is also there showing mail_url. But just next after that i am facing Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Comment: I tried with multiple account one is of my gmail and one is my office email account, On my office account server there is already enabled smtp.

Comment: priyanka this error is not related to MAIL_URL.You should  search for Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND . https://forums.meteor.com/t/error-getaddrinfo-enotfound/881/3